# set COMPLEX_UNIT_PX on Layout Parameters

Tags: android, user-interface, pixel

I am developing for two different devices and need to force pxs on one device's layoutparameter object through code when specifying width and height. How do I do that?

```
GridView.LayoutParams glp = new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            glp.width = 80; <- need to ensure this is in px or LDPI interprets it .75 of 80
            glp.height = 80;
```

Normally I would use setFontSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size) and it works. How about Layouts themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You need the params to be fixed? If you want to make sure adding pixels, create `dimen` resources e.g: 80px in string.xml then load in `LayoutParams`

`new GridView.LayoutParams(pixels, pixels);` They are already pixels.

See the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int, int)

Comment: ok cool as long as they are already pixels I am ok. The problem is when they are not and my 80 gets squashed. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you do not you use fixed width and height.